# How to change font size and colour in Mediawiki navigation sidebar and footer?

Tags: css, mediawiki

My website was developed using Mediawiki and I have the following question:

How do I change the font size and font colour in the navigation sidebar and footer?

I am using the vector skin and having difficulties finding the correct way to make these changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For the navigation:**

search in your css to

```
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a {
    color: #0645AD;
}
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a:visited {
    color: #0B0080;
}
```

and change it to

```
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a {
    font-size:16px;
    color: #008000;
}
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a:visited {
    color: #A0600B;
}
```

use this when you want the same color for a link and visited link

```
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body ul li a, a:visited {
    font-size:16px;
    color: #008000;
}
```

or simple add a new line with this code

```
#mw-panel .portal a, #mw-panel .portal a:visited {
    font-size:16px!important;
    color: red!important;
}
```

**For the Footer**

add new line with this code

```
div#footer ul li{
    font-size:16px!important;
    color:black!important;
}

div#footer ul li a,div#footer ul li a:visited {
    color: orange!important;
}
```

}

Comment: Adding the code to the bottom of the vector/screen.css file worked. thanks!