# MediaWiki: How do you change font size in the navigation sidebar?

Tags: css, mediawiki

I know very little about coding - can anyone provide explicit instructions about how to do the above?

A similar question was asked a couple of years ago: [How to change font size and colour in Mediawiki navigation sidebar and footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461308/how-to-change-font-size-and-colour-in-mediawiki-navigation-sidebar-and-footer)

However, it's not clear from the answer which file to change. The questioner then replied that they'd changed the code in `vector/screen.css`, but this file no longer exists. And I can't ask for clarification as I've submitted less than 50 comments.

I'd also like to be able to change the font size for the links in the top-right corner of the page, and along the top of the content area, and in the footer.

It would be nice if I could make these changes via the page `MediaWiki:Common.css` rather than a site file, as I did to change the size of the article text.

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate. Please see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS for info on how to change the CSS. There is no need to alter the skin source files. Normally you would just add you css rules to MediaWiki:Common.css, as noted on the linked page. The CSS rules from the linked answer still apply

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font size and colour in Mediawiki navigation sidebar and footer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461308/how-to-change-font-size-and-colour-in-mediawiki-navigation-sidebar-and-footer)

Comment: Thanks - the code from the other answer indeed works when I insert it into the MediaWiki:Common.css. Do you know what the code would be for making the same changes to the links in the top-right corner of the page, and along the top of the content area?

Comment: If you right-click on the elements you are interested in, and chose ”inspect” or similar, your browser will let see what CSS classes are used where. For a good introduction to CSS, see eg. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/intro-to-css/p/css-basics

Comment: Okay, thanks - I'll try that.